# Keep only difference between two JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web-crawler

I have a `JSON` version of a `DOM` tree and I want keep only the difference between pages (remove nav footer ...)

Example:

```
const a = {
    id: '1',
    child: [
        {
            id: '2',
            child: [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}]
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            child: [{id: '1'}, {id: '5'}]
        }
    ]
};
```

And

```
const b = {
    id: '1',
    child: [
        {
            id: '2',
            child: [{id: '1'}, {id: '4'}]
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            child: [{id: '1'}, {id: '4'}]
        }
    ]
};
```

With a function

```
diff(a, b)
```

This result

```
{
    id: '1', 
    child: [
        {
            id: '2', 
            child: [{id: '2'}]

        },
        {
            id: '3', 
            child: [{id: '5'}]
        }
    ]
}
```

I created this based on recursive function

```
const diff = (a, b) => {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {

  }

  if (typeof a === 'object') {
    // ...
    extract(a.child, b.child);
  }
}
```

How do I do this? Is there an `npm` package? or with `JSON` Path? I want to create a function that remove the equal '*parts*' between two `JSON` files with the output of the function having the same structure, but without the '*equal parts*' only difference.

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a little differently, this should get you the right values.

```
function diff(obj1, obj2) {
  var ret = {};
  for(var i in obj2) {
    if(!obj1.hasOwnProperty(i) || obj2[i] !== obj1[i]) {
      ret[i] = obj2[i];
    }
  }
  return ret;
};
```

See the code here with your example data https://jsbin.com/toboto/edit?js,console

This solution is not recursive though.  Alternatively, for a deep difference I recommend checking out this library https://github.com/flitbit/diff